# I dont understand why ".map" is undefined in this variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array.prototype.map

This .map object is undefined, but I don't know why. This line **"{noticias.map((noticia) => ("**

```
import React from 'react'
import Noticia from './Noticia'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const ListadoNoticias = ({noticias}) =>{

 return (
    <div className='row'>
        {noticias.map((noticia) => (
            <Noticia 
                key={noticia.url}
                noticia={noticia}
            />
        ))}
    </div>
 )
}


ListadoNoticias.propTypes = {
    noticias: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

export default ListadoNoticias;
```

The "noticias" variable comes from here

```
import React, {Fragment, useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Header from './components/Header'
import Formulario from './components/Formulario'
import ListadoNoticias from './components/ListadoNoticias'

function App() {

  // Definir a categoria e noticia
  const [categoria, guardarCategoria] = useState('') // Esse State guarda a categoria da noticia no hooks
  const [noticias, guardarNoticias] = useState([]) // Vai guadar o array de objetos da requisição em formato JSON

  useEffect(() => {
    const consultarAPI = async () => {
      const API = '81673cba4b934873953af1db871a6ac7'
      const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=br&category=${categoria}&apiKey=${API}`
      const resposta = await fetch(url)
      const noticias = await resposta.json()

      guardarNoticias(noticias.articles)
    }
    consultarAPI()
  }, [categoria]) // Vai usar esse State para mudar as informações da API

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Header 
        titulo='Buscador de Noticias'
      />
      <div className='container white'>
        <Formulario 
          guardarCategoria={guardarCategoria}
        />
        <ListadoNoticias 
          noticias={noticias}
        />
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Strangely this code is working on localhost. But when I upload to Netlify, it returns this error on the console. Please look at this image: [Error image in Netlify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKoQ6.png)

Comment: can you show where do you pass that prop?

Comment: Well he already did

Comment: pretty sure `noticias.articles` is not an array. Console.log `noticias.articles` and see what data is gives you

Comment: Seems like the request to `newsapi.org` fails (the first error in the console)

Comment: Comes this state `const [noticias, guardarNoticias] = useState([])` and use in this variable `const noticias = await resposta.json()`. I put this prop here `const ListadoNoticias = ({noticias}) =>{`

Comment: @CyrusZei articles is object's array. Look at this image https://i.imgur.com/ByAG81v.png

Comment: You can see in the error image you posted that your fetch request is returning a [426 error code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/426). The data you are expecting has not been retrieved and you don't have error handling set up to deal with it. The `articles` property on an unsuccesful network request message is going to be `undefined`, so that's what your state gets set with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that `fetch` is returning an error and your response handling doesn't handle successful failure responses, i.e. valid response that is an error. In this case you are receiving a 426 error status code.

You are likely setting your `noticias` to an undefined value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const consultarAPI = async () => {
    const API = '81673cba4b934873953af1db871a6ac7';
    const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=br&category=${categoria}&apiKey=${API}`;
    const resposta = await fetch(url); // <-- 426 error response
    const noticias = await resposta.json();

    guardarNoticias(noticias.articles); // <-- articles undefined
  }
  consultarAPI();
}, [categoria]);
```

The undefined `noticias` state is passed to `ListadoNoticias` and you attempt to map from it and the error is thrown.

## Solution

You should really surround `async/await` code in a `try/catch` to handle rejected promises and other various thrown errors. You should also check for a [successful fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful).

```
useEffect(() => {
  const consultarAPI = async () => {
    const API = '81673cba4b934873953af1db871a6ac7';
    const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=br&category=${categoria}&apiKey=${API}`;

    try {
      const resposta = await fetch(url);
      if (!resposta.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }
      const noticias = await resposta.json();
      guardarNoticias(noticias.articles);
    } catch(error) {
      // handle fetch failure or any other thrown errors
    }
  }
  consultarAPI();
}, [categoria]);
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Drew Reese. The only error now is that of 426. I think it's from the API. Look at this image: https://i.imgur.com/TLjy5Of.png

Comment: @YgorLourenco Seems the [HTTP status 426](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/426) is the backend API suggesting you should upgrade the used protocol on the request.